# Can't display images/css within my Django template

Tags: django, image, media

I am trying to setup static files and media locally and can't seem to get it to work.

[DIRECTORY HIERARCHY HERE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ixEX0.png)

## Settings.py

```
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR), 'static', 'img')
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

## Template Example

```
{% load staticfiles %}
<center><img class="img-responsive" src="{% static 'munter.png' %}" alt=""></center>
```

## URLS

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = [
   ...


] + static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT) + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Comment: Did you inspect browser error? If browser error is (404) then you have directory issue. Try to find which url leads you to that file then change settings or configuration according to that. My working settings is below if you want to check: 'STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = 'staticfiles'
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
)'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**First:** change the variable name `'MEIDA_ROOT'` to `'MEDIA_ROOT'`, to avoid futures problems.

**Second:** Change the `{% MEDIA_URL %}` to `{{ MEDIA_URL }}`

Comment: So, what if I just use static files and want to display an image?

Comment: django.contrib.staticfiles is included in your INSTALLED_APPS ?
and STATICFILES_DIRS ?